# Insert Object into Java Array

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, constructor

I got from my teacher the next assignment -

I need to build a `Course` class and `Student` class
and to insert every Student into the Course class
Each Student has an Id,name and grade.

I have tried the next code:

```
 public class Course {

    Student[] android = new Student[100];


    private void addStudent(Student a) {
        for (int i=0;i<android.length;i++) {
            if (android[i] == null) {
                android[i] = a;
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        addStudent(Joe);

    }

}
```

I need to insert a Student that i have created in the Students class to the first null position in the array.
When i try `addStudent(Joe);` it gives me an error : *"Joe cannot be resolved to a variable"*

The Student class code:

```
    public class Student {


                private float grade;
                private String name;
                private long id;
           public Student(long c,String b,float a) {
               grade = a;
               name = b;
               id = c;
           }
             public static void main(String[] args) {
             Student Joe = new Student(1,"Joe",40);
}
```

**The array holds 100 students (null at start)

- When adding a student - i need to check for the first null value in the array and put it 
  there
- When printing the students: i need to print only the non-null Objects in the array**

Comment: `Student[] android = new Student[100];` and `android[i] = a ;` - problem solved.

Comment: `Array[] Android = new Array[100];` -- I don't think this line does what you think it does.  Perhaps you want `Student[] camelCaseName = new Student[100];`?

Comment: Any of you should provide an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code

```
Array[] Android = new Array[100];
```

is creating an array of type `Array`, so you can only store `Array` objects in it.
If you want to store `Student`s, you need to create an array that, instead:

```
Student[] android = new Student[100];
```

Also, you need to realize that arrays in Java are indexed from 0.  That is, you cannot reference a position that is the same as the size of the array.  In your case, you have made 
an array with 100 elements, but your for-loop is trying to put 101 objects in it.

Furthermore, your question text implies you only want to insert the new `Student` object *once*, but your loop puts it into every empty location in your array.

Try this instead:

```
    for (int i=0;i<android.length;i++) { // < instead of <=, don't hardcode the length
        if (android[i] == null) {
            android[i] = a;
            break;                       // once we insert a, stop looping
        }
    }
```

### Update

The reason that the compiler can't find `Joe` is an issue of **scope**.  You have declared `Joe` as a **local** variable in the `main()` method in the `Student` class.  If you want the compiler to be able to see it, you need to declare it in the same method you are using it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Student Joe = new Student(1,"Joe",40);
    addStudent(Joe);
}
```

A quick google search of "Java variable scope tutorial" should give you plenty of reading about how and when you can use local and member variables.

Comment: Thanks,Worked.
But now i'm using `addStudent(Ofir);` and it gives me an error "Ofir cannot be resolved to a 
  variable" 

And Ofir is a Student ive made in the Students class.

Comment: It won't help you in the Student class unless it's public. Why not create Ofir in your Course class?

Comment: @Ambassador That's an entirely separate issue.  You should probably open a new question regarding it, or at least edit your original question and show us the code giving this problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
So there isn't a way to "addStudent" from the Course class without declaring it in the same method?

Comment: Every `Student` has to be instantiated somewhere.  If you want to use one that created elsewhere, you need to have a way to reference it, such as a **static** member, or perhaps as a parameter of another method in `Course`.  Take a look at [the Java tutorials on variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

insert method of student S (1111,"ahmed",3.5)in the position "p" in array of students(id,name,GBG)array size 100 and curent size =3.

-remove method that remove the student having GBG =2.5from the array of student .array size 100 and currentsize=3

Answer (score 0):

First, change the

```
Array[] Android = new Array[100];
```

to

```
Student[] listOfStudent = new Student[100];
```

What this does is creates a array of size 100, and the type of the array is Students, which is what you will be inserting into the array. You are also going to have to change

```
for (int i=0;i<=100;i++) {
        if (Android[i] == null) {
            Android[i] = a;

        }
}
```

to

```
for(int i=0; i < listOfStudents.length; i++){
    if(listOfStudents[i] == null){
        listOfStudent[i] = a;
    }
}
```

otherwise you will get a "List Out of Bounds" error. It is better to not hard code values into your code - good practice for the future!

Good Luck!